# Cuda: Declaring a device constant as a template

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I am working on a CUDA program that uses templates. The kernels would be instantiated with the datatype `cuComplex`, or `cuDoubleComplex`. Depending on the datatype with which the kernel is instantiated, I need to declare a constant which would reside in the constant memory space of the CUDA device. For implementing this, I've done:

```
// declared this globally
template <typename T> 
__device__ __constant__ T some_constant;
// set the constant through a function call in main().

// kernel templated
template <typename T>    
__global__ void kernel()
{
    T b_k = cuGet<T>(0.0, 0.0);
    T x_k_1 = cuGet<T>(2.0, 2.0); 
    // cuGet returns a complex no. of type 
    // cuComplex or cuDoubleComplex depending on T.

    b_k = cuAdd(b_k, cuMul(some_constant, x_k_1));
    // cuAdd, cuMul, cuGet are all overloaded functions.
    // They can take cuComplex, or cuDoubleComplex params.

    // Here, some_constant has to cuComplex or cuDoubleComplex, depending 
    // on the datatype of the other arg x_k_1 to cuMul.
    // Therefore, I went about implementing a templated constant.
}
```

On compiling, this gives an error: "some_constant" is not a function or static data member.

One option to solve this issue could be to define a type conversion from `cuDoubleComplex` to `cuComplex`, and declare the constant to be of `cuDoubleComplex` instead of using it as a template and, typecast the constant wherever it's being used in the kernel.

Is there any other way apart from this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that global variables can be defined as template variables in C++?

Comment: No, I am not sure about that.

Comment: I think your typecasting idea is possible, and not terribly onerous.  [Here's a worked example](http://pastebin.com/1kt5PUVM).  I'm not offering it as an answer, since you specifically are asking for "any other way apart from this".  It's possible your question is not answerable as written.

Comment: C++14 allows variable templates :) In C++<14 the workaround for what Rahul wants to do would be to make `some_constant` a static member of a class template, but that would be incompatible with `__constant__`. If `some_constant` is truly a constant (i.e. a compile-time constant), perhaps `__constant__` isn't really necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the main request is to avoid the type conversion, you can work around it with a template class with inline device functions (the rest being inspired from proposal by @RobertCrovella in a comment). Finally, a macro will make the call (it is not a perfectly clean design indeed, but keeps the same syntax). Here is an example of how it could work:

```
template <typename T> 
struct holder
{
    static __device__ __inline__ T value () ;
    static __device__ __inline__ void init (T val) ;
} ;

__constant__ char data [16] ;

__device__ __inline__ int holder<int>::value () { return *((int*)data); }
__device__ __inline__ long holder<long>::value () { return *((long*)data); }

#define some_constant holder<T>::value()

template <typename T>
__global__ void kernel(T* res)
{
    *res = some_constant ;
}

int main ()
{
    int *dres ;
    cudaMalloc <> (&dres, sizeof(int)) ;
    int val = 42 ;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol (data, &val, sizeof(int)) ;

    kernel<int><<<1,1>>>(dres) ;
    int hres ;
    cudaMemcpy (&hres, dres, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) ;
    printf ("RES = %d\n", hres) ;
}
```

The `holder<T>::value()` call will get inlined, type conversion erased by optimizer, and return the appropriate type from constant memory with no conversion (here the generated ptx):

```
// .globl   _Z6kernelIiEvPT_
.const .align 4 .b8 data[16];

.visible .entry _Z6kernelIiEvPT_(
    .param .u32 _Z6kernelIiEvPT__param_0
)
{
    .reg .b32   %r<4>;


    ld.param.u32    %r1, [_Z6kernelIiEvPT__param_0];
    cvta.to.global.u32  %r2, %r1;
    ld.const.u32    %r3, [data];
    st.global.u32   [%r2], %r3;
    ret;
}
```

The main downside being the macro which expects type to be `T`.

Comment: Beware that this does not work for two kernels of differing types being used. You'd either have to call cudaMemcpyToSymbol before every different kernel run, which is impossible if they run in different threads, or you could modify the `value` method to use differing offsets for differing types using a multiplier with the assumed maximum data type size, i.e., `return *( (T*)( (T_Largest*) data + sizeof(T) / sizeof( T_Smallest ) - 1 )` also you'd have to allocate enough data: `char data[ sizeof( T_Largest ) * ( sizeof( T_Largest ) / sizeof( T_Smallest ) ) ]`